# New to C# - problems with link labels and functions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linklabel

I am brand new to C# and have previously only written programs in JavaScript, so go easy on me !

I have written an "app launcher" program which reads a text file line by line.  Each line is just a path to a program e.g. C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\Gravity.exe

So far, my program can successfully read each line and produce a list of links.  As intended, each link appears as the path itself.

The problem I am having is that these links will not work.  However they WILL work if they are all just given the same fixed path.  I would like each link to use its .Text property as the destination.  (please see the comments "works" and "does not work" in my code below).  The only error I get is "cannot find the file specified".

I would really appreciate any help on this as I am finding C# a lot harder than Javascript !

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   //on form load
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string myfile = @"c:\users\matt\desktop\file.txt";

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(myfile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(line);   //check whats on each line

            LinkLabel mylinklabel = new LinkLabel();        //LinkLabel tells us the type of the object   e.g.  string mystring ="hello";
            mylinklabel.Text = line;
            this.Controls.Add(mylinklabel);
            mylinklabel.Location = new Point(0, 30 + counter * 30);

            mylinklabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(LinkClick);

            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();
    }

    private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Process.Start(this.Text);  //doesn't work
        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\gravity.exe");   //works
    }        
}
```

**Update:**

Thank you for your comments guys.  I have changed the line in question to:

```
Process.Start(((LinkLabel)sender).Text);
```

... and it does indeed work.  But perhaps I could ask a question about this line, as I am finding the syntax a little unusual and confusing.

Isn't `sender` a property of the `LinkLabel` object?  So to reference it, shouldn't we use `LinkLabel.sender`?  (this would be more JavaScript style !  I don't understand the `(LinkLabel)sender` notation)

I also do not understand:

```
private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

What does a space mean? Such as between `object` and `sender`? Or between `System.EventArgs` e?  `LinkClick` is the name of the event, but why do we have two things here, separated by a comma?

As you can tell, I am currently finding the C# syntax a bit hard going!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user: Welcome to StackOverflow, but FYI, StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so we don't use "Hi", or "Thanks", or signatures.

Comment: @user What you need is a tutorial on C#. After that things should be much clearer to you.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `this.Text` appears to be at least one of the problems.

`this` refers to the current instance of your class. What you want is the instance of the `LinkLabel` that was clicked. Fortunately, the event's `sender` argument provides this information.

So try something like this instead.

```
LinkLabel lnk = sender as LinkLabel;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lnk.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In that context "this.Text" refers to your FORMS text caption. User ((LinkLabel)sender).Text

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkLabel ll = (LinkLabel)sender;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ll.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example tells you better way to achieve this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

```
 private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine which link was clicked within the LinkLabel.
        this.linkLabel1.Links[linkLabel1.Links.IndexOf(e.Link)].Visited = true;

        // Display the appropriate link based on the value of the 
        // LinkData property of the Link object.
        string target = e.Link.LinkData as string;

        // If the value looks like a URL, navigate to it.
        // Otherwise, display it in a message box.
        if(null != target && target.StartsWith("www"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
        }
        else
        {    
            MessageBox.Show("Item clicked: " + target);
        }
    }
```